# How to get Azure DevOps client using python script

Tags: python, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to get client of Azure DevOps by using python script. 
Here is the code that I am using for this purpose:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
   git_client = p_context.connection.clients.get_git_client()
```

p_context is access token of my Azure DevOps organization.

Following is the error that I am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/IdentifyGitBuildCommitItems.py", line 95, in <module>
    t = get_commit_changes_for_build(context ,azdevops_projectid ,azdevops_build_id ,azdevops_build_number ,bld_commit.id ,azdevops_repository_name)
  File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/IdentifyGitBuildCommitItems.py", line 51, in get_commit_changes_for_build
    comt = git_client.get_changes(p_commit_id ,repository_id=p_repository_name ,project=p_project_id)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.10/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/devops/released/git/git_client_base.py", line 250, in get_changes
    query_parameters=query_parameters)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.10/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/devops/client.py", line 104, in _send
    response = self._send_request(request=request, headers=headers, content=content, media_type=media_type)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.10/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/devops/client.py", line 68, in _send_request
    self._handle_error(request, response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.10/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/devops/client.py", line 295, in _handle_error
    status_code=response.status_code))
azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsClientRequestError: Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code.
##[error]/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.10/x64/bin/python failed with return code: 1
```

This is the full GitHub example that I am following for my use case: https://github.com/venkatra/dbt_hacks/blob/PERSISTENT_TABLE_MATERIALIZATION/IdentifyGitBuildCommitItems.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue and resolve the error.
Error was prompting due to my source code was present in my personal GitHub account not in the Azure Git repository. When I moved source code from personal Git to Azure Git repository error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) and try the following code:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'YOURPAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YOURORG'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client 
git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()
```